# JQM: URL from popup opens url and returns to current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to open a page when the user clicks save. 
However, the page opens and than goes back to display current page. It uses the link I need but shows a different page. meaning if I click refresh it will display the page I need.

How to fix it? (I need the save function, cause I'm doing some ajax requests to get data, can't do href=..., needs to come from function)

calling popup

```
<a href="#popupSave" data-rel="popup" data-inline="true" data-icon="check" data-theme="b" data-role="button" data-position-to="window">Save</a>
```

popup

```
 <div data-role="popup" id="popupSave" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="ui-corner-top">
                <h1>Save?</h1>
            </div>
                <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
                <h3 class="ui-title">To Save?</h3>
                <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>
                <a href="" id="link" onclick="save();" data-role="button" data-inline="true"  data-theme="b" >Save</a> <!---->
                </div>
            </div>
```

js function

```
function save(){

  $("#popupSave").popup('close');
 $.mobile.changePage("pro_open.html?flag=change");
}
```

Solved!!!---> It was the:

```
 function save(){

  $("#popupSave").popup('close');//<----causing the problem, removed it and it works!
 $.mobile.changePage("pro_open.html?flag=change");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!!---> It was the:

```
 function save(){
```

$("#popupSave").popup('close');//<----causing the problem, removed it and it works!
 $.mobile.changePage("pro_open.html?flag=change");
}